# Copy file from path to Path in Android 11

Tags: java, storage

I hope you are fine.

After I have done all steps, of getting permission storage in Android 11, now I can create, copy files from assets to any folder, or delete files.

I just got a problem when try to copy file from path to path, the problem is I find the output file empty.

Only in this I need help, and I hope you help me and tell me what mistake I have in my code, and thanks in advance.

To copy I'm using:

```
Uri muri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3Aagora%2file.txt");
Uri uri2 = Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AAlarms");
DocumentFile mfile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(MainActivity.this, muri);
DocumentFile mfile1 = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(MainActivity.this, uri2);
mfile1 = mfile1.createFile("file/txt", "file.txt");
uri2 = mfile1.getUri();
if (copyFileFromUri2(MainActivity.this, muri, uri2)) {
    showMessage("file copied successfully");
} else {
    showMessage("failed to copy the file !");
}
```

The method:

```
public boolean copyFileFromUri2(Context context, Uri fileUri, Uri targetUri)
{
    InputStream fis = null;
    OutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        ContentResolver content = context.getContentResolver();
        fis = content.openInputStream(fileUri);
        fos = content.openOutputStream(targetUri);
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int length = 0;
        while ((length = fis.read(buff)) > 0) {
            fos.write(buff, 0, length);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (fis != null) {
            try {
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (fos != null) {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to initialize the `OutputStream os` as follows:

```java
fos = new BufferedOutputStream( content.openOutputStream(targetUri))
```